# Use variables inside a quoted string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In php you can use variables inside of double-quotes.  eg:

```
$dog = "scooby";
echo "$dog $dog doo";
```

Is it possible to do something similar in javascript **without** breaking the string up into pieces:

```
var dog = "scooby";
alert($dog + " " + $dog + " doo");
```

Thanks (in advance) for your help.

Comment: Well, you'd do it without the $, but `alert(dog + " " + dog + " doo");` is the javascript way.

Comment: Just remove dollar signs from your example and it should work.

Comment: You could use some kind of `sprintf` implementation in JS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can’t. Javascript does not have [string interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation), so you must concatenate:

```
var dog = "fido"
dog + " " + dog + " doo"
```

Answer (score 1):

No, since there is no escape character for variables in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Natively, not possible. However if you don't mind using a library, you can use this Javascript implementation of [sprintf](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf).

Instead of:

```
var dog = "scooby";
alert($dog + " " + $dog + " doo");
```

You would use:

```
alert(sprintf('%s %s doo', 'dog', 'dog'));
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use string replace

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

If you want it to be done depending upon the token, you'd need a little more work:

```
function replacer(match, p1,  string){
  // p1 is the first group (\w+)
  var stuff = {
     dog: "woof", 
     cat: "meow"
  };
  return stuff[p1] || "";
};
newString = "A dog says $dog. A cat says $cat.".replace(/\$(\w+)/g, replacer);
```

results in

```
"A dog says woof. A cat says meow."
```

Edit: Actually, if you want to do a kind of string interpolation on global variables, it's also pretty easy, though *I wouldn't recommend this*.  **Please don't** unless you have a really good reason.  And if you say you have a good reason, I probably wouldn't believe you. My first example, where I give a particular dictionary/object to search, is *much* better.  *Please don't go about polluting the global namespace just because this works!*

```
var dog ="woof";
var cat = "meow";
function replacer(match, p1,  string){
  return window[p1] || "";
};
newString = "A dog says $dog. A cat says $cat.".replace(/\$(\w+)/g, replacer);
```